# How to re-attempt a faulty task in C#?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, retry-logic

I want to implement re-attempt logic for X amount of times to complete a single task.

Here is what I have done

```
private async Task ExecuteTasks(List<Task> tasks)
{
    foreach(var task in tasks)
    {
        // first attempt!
        await task;

        int failedCounter = 0;

        if(task.IsFaulted)
        {
            while(++failedCounter <= 3)
            {
                // Here retry the task.
                task.Start(); // this throws an exception.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `task.Start()` will throw an exception since the status is already faulted. How can I reset the status of a task? If this is not possible, how do I create a task from a previous failed task?

Comment: Tasks aren't threads, they can't be restarted. There's no point in using `Task.Start` as if they were threads. They are *promises* that something will complete in the future. The Task/Promise may execute on an already existing Threadpool thread, or it may represent the completion of an IO or network operation, in which case it doesn't run anywhere

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you. Is there a way to create a new task from previously faulted task so the new task in run using a new promise?

Comment: The thing that needs to be retried is the *asynchronous function*, not the task. This could be as easy as `while(retries-->0){ await DoSomethingAsync(); return;}`. Libraries like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) allow using complex retry strategies, with exponential delays, short-circuiting etc. .NET Core's HttpClientFactory integrates with Polly directly to implement retry strategies when calling remote APIs

Comment: Does this mean `await` will execute the action into a new task always? so adding `await task;` followed by `await task;` will execute the same callback using 2 promises?

Comment: `Is there a way to create a new task ...` that's the same question, reworded. I didn't use the word `Promise` by accident. In other languages, eg JavaScript, `Promise` is the actual word used for this. A Task only represents a Promise that something will complete in the future and *maybe* return a results, not the action itself

Comment: `await will execute` no, await *awaits* for that promise to complete, without blocking the current thread. Calling `await task` twice will only await once. The second time, the task is already completed.

Comment: So instead of looping through tasks, I should loop through callbacks which is used to create new task each time I want to execute the callback. yes?

Comment: *"Tasks aren't threads, they can't be restarted."* -- Threads can't be restarted either.